# A doubt on a statement about simple algebras in Weil's Basic Number Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The following is from Chapter IX, Section 1, Corollary 5 of Weil's classical book mentioned in the title
[image]

In the proof of Corollary 5, he used the fact that the kernel of $F_L$ is a two-sided ideal, but since $F_L$ is just a $L$-linear map, we can not deduce such a result. So do we should suppose the map $F$ in Corollary 5 is a homomorphism of $K$-algebras? But if so why Weil stressed that $F$ is $K$-linear. I am grateful for any comment or answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the kernel $N$ is a two-sided ideal by linearity. For any $x\in L,$ $f(xy) = xf(y)$ by linearity, so that if $f(y) = 0$ then $xf(y) = 0.$ Similarly, $f(yx) = 0.$ (You're right that you'd need it to be a map of algberas to get $f(xy)=f(x)f(y),$ but linearity still tells you $f(xy) = xf(y)$ for $x\in L.$)

Comment: I am confused, since to prove that $N$ is a two-sided ideal of $A_L$, we need to show that for any $x\in A_L$ (not $L$), $xN\subset N$ and $Nx\subset N$. So for this we have to assume $F_L$ is a homomorphism of algebras. Am I right?